# Flutter GetX Changing Theme needs Hot Reload?

Tags: flutter, dart

hi guys I'm using the flutter GetX package to change my app ThemeMode. it works fine but the problem is it needs a hot reload to change the ThemeMode here is my code

`changeThemeMode() {darkModeSwitch.value == true? Get.changeTheme(Apptheme.dark): Get.changeTheme(Apptheme.light);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need it.

Make ensure which you are using `GetMaterialApp` instead of `MaterialApp`.
Here's how I got it:

```
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

I create a `changeTheme` method to do it

```
 void changeTheme() {
    Get.changeTheme(Get.isDarkMode ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark());
  }
```

And I call him in the page like that:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: changeTheme,
  child: Icon(Icons.add),
),
```

That's works for me.

Comment: thanks  man , but my problem was i'm using Get.theme instead of Them.of(context) , that was my problem any way thanks for your answer again :) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    isDarkMode = settings.read('isDarkMode') ?? false;
    ever(_isDarkMode, (_) => settings.write('isDarkMode', isDarkMode));
    ever(
        _isDarkMode,
        (_) => Get.changeTheme(
            _isDarkMode.value ? getDarkTheme() : getLightTheme()));
    
  }

...

ThemeData getDarkTheme() {
  return darkTheme;
}
ThemeData getLightTheme() {
  return lightTheme;
}
```

This code is an example of using getStorage to save setting values to a local device and turning on/off dark mode by manipulating a switch.

```
 ever(
        _isDarkMode,
        (_) => Get.changeTheme(
            _isDarkMode.value ? getDarkTheme() : getLightTheme()));

This may help you
```

Comment: please feel free to ask more about it